# Can I use onclick for a second event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, translation

I want to use onclick() to translate my website into french.
Then I would like to use the same method to translate back in English.

Here is the code. Any idea ? Thanks !

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Translate</title>

<script language="JavaScript">

function TranslateToFrench()
{
    MyText.innerText = "Ceci est un texte en Français.";
    languageBox.innerText = "English";
}

function TranslateToEnglish()
{
    MyText.innerText = "This is a text in English.";
    languageBox.innerText = "Français";
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <h3 id="languageBox" align="right" onclick="TranslateToFrench()">Français</h3>   

    <p id="MyText">This is a text in English.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Translate</title>

<script>

var app = 0;

function Translate()

   if(app == 0){
        app = 1;
        TranslateToFrench();

   }else{
        app = 0;
        TranslateToEnglish();
   }
}

function TranslateToFrench()
{
    MyText.innerText = "Ceci est un texte en Français.";
    languageBox.innerText = "English";
}

function TranslateToEnglish()
{
    MyText.innerText = "This is a text in English.";
    languageBox.innerText = "Français";
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <h3 id="languageBox" align="right" onclick="Translate()">Français</h3>   

    <p id="MyText">This is a text in English.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if the solution enjoy you and satisfy you, you can accept the answer: D

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. I'm new to this website. No prob :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just check  `h3` elements `innerText` and on that call the proper function

Try:

```
function TranslateToFrench()
{
    if(languageBox.innerText==="Français"){    
        MyText.innerText = "Ceci est un texte en Français.";
        languageBox.innerText = "English";}
    else{
        TranslateToEnglish();
    }
}

function TranslateToEnglish()
{
    MyText.innerText = "This is a text in English.";
    languageBox.innerText = "Français";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6g3Z2/1/)